# Existence results for this ODE? (periodic)

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Are there any existence/uniqueness results for solutions to the ODE
$$y'(t) = f(y(t),t)$$
$$y(0) = y(T)$$
on the time interval $[0,T]$ where $f$ is Caretheodory and $T$-periodic in $t$.

I am looking for $y \in C^0$ say and $y' \in L^2$.

Comment: [Nonlinear Functional Analysis](http://books.google.com/books/about/Nonlinear_Functional_Analysis.html?id=Gz04Rv8G3OcC) by Deimling has several results for such equations, perhaps under more restrictive assumptions on $f$. But you need more than the Carathéodory condition anyway, to avoid silly counterexamples like  $y'=|t|^{-1/2}$.